# Interfaz Cloneable para sobreescribir método clone

Tags: java

tengo una duda con esta interfaz. Según las pruebas que he hecho, para sobreescribir el método clone de Object se puede implementar o no esta interfaz, pero indagando es una interfaz vacía. En mi libro dice que hay que implementarla y si no se hace hay que capturar la excepción CloneNotSupportedException, pero probándolo hay que capturarla si o si según los avisos del EDI.

Cuál es entonces la utilidad de esta interfaz?

Gracias anticipadas.

Un cordial saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Es una interfaz de marcado - si una clase la implementa debe implementar *clone*. Pero como *clone* está en Object no hay necesidad de ponerla en la interfaz. Si hubiese un método clone en Cloneable no podrías implementarla en ninguna clase porque todas las clases tienen como padre Object y tendrías dos métodos con el mismo nombre. Pero al implementar una intrerfaz vacia de marcado sabes que tu clase implementa clone.

Comment: No entiendo el término interfaz de marcado, para qué es útil? Todo funciona igual que si no se utiliza o eso me parece. Según la documentación si no se implementa esta interfaz, clone lanza la excepción CloneNotSupportedException y en mis pruebas hay que capturarla si o si.

Comment: Aquí tienes algo más de explicaciones - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850328/marker-interfaces-in-java. Por lo general las interfaces de marcado te dicen que la clase que las implementa "sabe" hacer algo y en tiempo de ejecución estás seguro que lo hará.